# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'. Its a Routing error

Tags: flutter

The error is when I try to use the ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments I get an error. Also I want to save it in a map but can't.

```
Map data = {};
data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments; // this is the error;
```

> Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

Comment: Read this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Comment: can you give your solution that anyone can be helpful..

Comment: after doing this i got null error i dont know.

Answer (score 40):

After passing so many problems, finally, the solution is surprisingly easy.

```
Map data = {};
data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
```

Answer (score 14):

Try using:

```
data=ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as Map;
```

The `?` is used for null safety

Answer (score 5):

after lot of searching this coda works

```
Map data = {};
data = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the below code:

```
Map <String, Object>data = {}; // as the arguments passed from 
data = {"dataKey":ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments};
```

And later, access your arguments by calling

`data["dataKey"]` `// it will return the arguments`

Comment: Hi thank you so much. God bless you. It didn't work at first but then all I had to do is add a null safety to it

Comment: If you think that the answer is working for your case, then please mark it as done, so that other people will find it as a soultion.

Comment: I have the same problem. How do you add a null safety on documentSnapshot.data()?

Comment: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<>' in type cast thats error

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue and I think this solution will help you

```
Map data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code inside of your StatefulWidget class

```
Map userdata = {};
userdata = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
print(userdata);
```

Your output looks like something this

```
flutter: {firstName: Dhaval, lastname: Gevariya}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the argument Like :

   class ProductDetailsArguments {
   final Product product;

   ProductDetailsArguments({required this.product});

   }
2. extracts the arguments Like

   final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ProductDetailsArguments;

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I did :

Map <String, dynamic> data = {};
data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;