# Flutter data["dataKey"] How can I return one specific argument?

Tags: flutter, dart, return, arguments, datakey

[A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'. Its a Routing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522828/a-value-of-type-object-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-type-mapdynamic#)

Im referring to this question. How can I return one specific argument?
data["dataKey"] just gives me all arguments.

Comment: Why do you want to assign them to map?

Comment: Using a class full of named parameters and need to return them now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like-

```
MapEntry _entry = data.entries.singleWhere((element)=><Expression>);
print(_entry.value);
```

Example

```
Map<String, int> data = {'one': 1, 'two': 2};
MapEntry _entry = data.entries.singleWhere((element) => element.key == 
'one');
print(_entry.key);// it will print "one"
print(_entry.value); //it will print 1
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. but is there nothing I can do to return one specific argument just by using some modification of `print(data["dataKey"]` ?