# Flutter pass settings.arguments to MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I use a function to perform all my routing. I now need to pass some arguments to CustomerDeskSearchResultsView and I do following:

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  final args = settings.arguments;
  switch (settings.name) {
    case homeViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeView());
    case privateKeyViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ScanPrivateKeyView());
    case userProfileViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ProfileView());
    case userTasViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TasView());
    case aboutViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AboutView());
    case customerDeskViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CustomerDeskSelectView());
    case customerDeskSearchResultsViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
  CustomerDeskSearchResultsView(searchType: '', searchValue: ''));
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Error404Screen());
  }
}
```

The passed arguments are searchType and searchValue. How to retrieve this from settings.arguments? args['searchType'] and args['searchvalue'] does not work.

Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best if you create a data class that holds the values:

```
class SearchTypeAndValueData {
   String searchType;
   String searchValue;

   SearchTypeAndValueData({required this.searchType, required this.searchValue})
}
```

Then you can have this data object as:

```
SearchTypeAndValueData data = settings.arguments as SearchTypeAndValueData;
```

Another way without using an extra class like that, arguments can be anything. In your case it might be a list so you can do this:

```
List<dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments as List<dynamic>;
```

But in this case you need to know on which index what data you can find, then pass it to your class:

```
CustomerDeskSearchResultsView(searchType: arguments[0], searchValue: arguments[1]));
```

Obivously you also can pass your data as a map. Then you have to convert the `settings.arguments` to a map.

Then you will be able to retrieve them like this:

```
arguments['searchType'] and arguments['searchvalue']
```

Comment: I opted for the Class holding the variables and I have no more errors, But launching the app now, throws an exception like : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'SearchTypeAndValueData' in type cast

Comment: Then you call that page with no arguments given to the routing.

Comment: I understand but the error occurs when launching the app, immediately after the splashscreen. The sceen is not yet called.

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522828/a-value-of-type-object-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-type-mapdynamic)

Answer (score 0):

This way you are passing the values to the `Constructor` not to the `arguments`, so you can easily use them inside the screen because they are already defined as properties (variables) in the class.

Comment: Yes correct. But the question is how to pass the variables to the Constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not clear.